# Are sockets.io messages sent with FIFO order?

Tags: javascript, events, socket.io

Can I rely on the order of emission of multiple messages when receiving them on the client side?

For example consider this code:

#### Server side

```
let io = require('socket.io')(80);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.emit('myevent', 'First event');
    socket.emit('myevent', 'Second event');
})
```

#### Client side

```
let socket = new io()
    .on('myevent', (msg) => {
        console.log(msg);
    })
```

Can I be sure that the messages will be logged in the right order, I mean:

```
First event
Second event
```

Comment: Yes, it's a TCP socket.

Comment: Yes. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14933868/message-ordering-in-socket-io .